# Tag synonyms and data dump

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, data-explorer, tag-synonyms

Now that the [tag synonyms are implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), how does it affect the monthly data dump?

Should the data dump have the list of tag synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this should be added since it's public information. I don't think there will be many queries wanting to run on this table, but making the data available will let us get statistics on the tag synonym performance itself.

Adding this information as a new table would make the most sense, and it wouldn't be difficult to implement. Here is how the schema would look in Data Explorer:

```
TagSynonyms
-----------
SourceTagId (FK to Tags.Id)
TargetTagId (FK to Tags.Id)
Creator (FK to Users.Id)
CreatedDate (DateTime, NOT NULL)
RenameCount (int, NOT NULL)
LastRenameTime (DateTime, NULL)

PK: (SourceTagId, TargetTagId)
```

The only column I'm not sure about is `LastRenameTime`. Since the data won't be totally live, it would be a bit useless to include it. But since that information is displayed on the tag synonyms page, I suppose it should be included for completeness.

The tag synonym system is still in development, so I would imagine this is already `[status-planned]` -- they may just be waiting until the schema is finalized after the new enhancements are added soon. Although, it would seem this one table is more or less done -- there's just going to be more features added to assist in adding entries to this table.

Comment: Re LastRenameTime, it might be useful to see that the last rename was, for example, 6 months ago.  For very active tags, the date will of course be the last day of the month, but it looks like this won't be the case for most tags.

Answer (score 4):

The table [TagSynonyms](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/270298/all-tagsynonyms) is available on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) with the following columns:

| Column_name | Type | Length | Prec | Scale | Null? | Collation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | int | 4 | 10 | 0 | no |  |
| SourceTagName | nvarchar | 50 |  |  | no | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS |
| TargetTagName | nvarchar | 50 |  |  | no | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS |
| CreationDate | datetime | 8 |  |  | no |  |
| OwnerUserId | int | 4 | 10 | 0 | no |  |
| AutoRenameCount | int | 4 | 10 | 0 | no |  |
| LastAutoRename | datetime | 8 |  |  | yes |  |
| Score | int | 4 | 10 | 0 | no |  |
| ApprovedByUserId | int | 4 | 10 | 0 | yes |  |
| ApprovalDate | datetime | 8 |  |  | yes |  |

as found in the [Data dictionary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

At the time of the last edit the table holds <s>2930</s> 4331 rows.