# Is it possible to download the SO Tags database?

Tags: support, tags, data-dump, tag-synonyms

Is there a way for me to download the full list of tags (and synonyms) used on Stack Overflow?
My intent is to import these tags into an SQLite database as part of a process to convert all of my delicious bookmarks and tags to the ones used here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, you can only get a list of tags. Tag synonyms are not publicly available yet, but [have already been requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57514/tag-synonyms-and-data-dump).

There are a few ways of going about getting the data:

- Download the latest [Data Dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/), and use an XML parser to extract the tag information
- Use the [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com) (a public-facing data dump loaded into SQL Server) and one of the techniques described in my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62573/how-to-access-all-of-odata-in-stackoverflow-data-explorer/62581#62581).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Get a data dump and parse the tags field on each record.  It's not a nicely wrapped package of just the tags, and parsing them is not straightforward, but it's not bad either.